# How do you activate built in modules in nose2 test framework that don't come pre-loaded?

Tags: python-3.x, nose2

I am trying to load the "layers" plugin in nose2, but I can't figure out the format for the configuration file.  The documentation is here: http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/layers.html , but it doesn't include the module name to list in the configuration file.  I have previously loaded third party plugins for nose2, but am having trouble now with pre-installed plugins that aren't pre-loaded.  This is what I have for my configuration file right now:

```
[unittest]
plugins = nose2_html_report.html_report
          layers.Layers
          layers.LayerReport

[html-report]
always-on = True

[layers-report]
always-on = True
```

When I try to run using this .cfg file, I get an error saying that layers.Layers isn't a package.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've just been looking into same question!

The following worked for me.

```
[unittest]
plugins = nose2.plugins.layers
```